# Login com Asp.net 4.5 (Entity Framework)?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, webforms

Como consigo fazer um Select utilizando `Entity Framework`, e verificar se o registro existe ?

***Exemplo:***

```
txtlogin.text
txtsenha.text
```

Tabela Login.

- campo usuario
- campo senha

`valida()` classe criada para executar o comando e ao selecionar o `valida()` ele vai verificar se existe o `usuario` e `senha` via `Entity Framework`

Comment: Você não pode validar antes de enviar para o Entity? de qualquer modo, cadê o código, tem como você colocar? Não da para usar Data anotations? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg193959(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu uso assim:

```
using(var context = new SeuContexto()){
      var Usuario = context.login.firstOrDefault(x=> x.usuario == txtlogin.text && x.senha == txtsenha.text)
      if(Usuario != null)
      {
            //Existe o usuário
      }else
      {
            //Se voltar nulo, não existe o usuário com esta senha
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o método `Any()` do LINQ. Ele retorna `true` se existir algum (*any* em inglês) registro. Se não existir retorna `false`. Ex:

```
if(contexto.Entidade.Any(x => x.Login == txtLogin.Text && x.Senha == txtSenha.Text))
{
    //existe
}
else
{
    //não existe
}
```

---

A documentação do método `Any()` você pode ver [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx).